# Only allow whole numbers in input field

Tags: javascript, decimal

```
function isNumber(n) {
    var j = n.trim();
  return (j % 1 === 0 && j != "");
}
```

My function still returns true if the inputted value is "14.0". It should only allow whole numbers without any decimal.

Comment: If in ES6 environment, use `Number.isInteger`. If IE>=10, use `pattern="\d+"` attribute on the input element.

Answer (score 5):

You can use regex for this

```js
function isWhole(n) {
  return /^\d+$/.test(n);
}

$("#number").change(function() {
  if (isWhole($(this).val())) {
    $(".error").hide();
  } else {
    $(".error").show();
  }
});
```

```css
.error {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="number" name="number" />
<p class="error">Whole numbers only</p>
```

Comment: This doesn't work per OP's requirement. `var moon = 1234.0` returns true.

Comment: Hmm.. The regex only matches numbers and no other character including . but I guess that applies to strings only.

Comment: The one and only, memory-stealing Google Chrome. The problem is that after `var moon = 1234.0; var str = moon.toString()`, `str` is equal to `"1234"`.

Comment: I guess 1234.0 is treated as 1234 if it is a type "number". But since OP is calling trim on the variable n, I think we can assume that it is a string.

Comment: I am always staggered by how much jQuery someone can fit in an answer that isn't even about jQuery. Especially when it's several times more code than the actual answer.

Comment: @PrathikRajendranM is right. It;s treated as a string.

Comment: @RobG that was just to demonstrate it working, the function is not in jQuery. However I get your point. How to add 2+2 in javascript? var v = 2 + 2; Downvoted cos not enough jquery.

Comment: @RobG Also Rob, I don't think using jQuery to demonstrate a functionality is wrong. It is concise and it is good to show the working of a code since they could directly copy it from here and know it works as per their need. I don't agree with this anti-jQuery brigade that irrationally targets anything that has jQuery in it.

Answer (score 1):

Try treating it as a string and use the match function with regex to see if there is a decimal there. You can use `yourVariable.match (/[0-9]*(\.)[0-9]*/)`. It will return true if there is a decimal there.

Comment: The OP is looking for string integers, so `/^\d+$/.test(value)` does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Abuse the round() function. That will get rid of the garbage:

```
function isNumber(n) {
  if(Math.round(n)==n && n.length==(Math.round(n)).length) 
    return n;
  else return false;
}
```

Essentially this function returns false if the number is not an integer, and returns the exact integer if it is an integer.

Input 14.0 should return false

Input 13.5 should return false

Input 13 should return 13.

Comment: Why would you return the rounded number? Why not just `return Math.round(n) == n`?

Comment: Suppose your input is 14.0. Then the Math.round(n)==n is true. WHen you then return n, you still have the 14.0. If you return the Math.round(n), you will get 14 instead (the desired result).

Comment: But if the input is 14.0, OP wants it to return false.

Comment: Ah, sorry, misread that. See edit above (in a minute)

Comment: Still fails :/. I really, honestly thought this might've worked though.

Comment: I did not test the code. Should work for maybe except the (Math.round(n)).length: That is not checked. Might need to be cast as string first.